# Ubuntu Server ping down

Tags: networking, server, connection, ping

Please help me I am completely new to this. My dedicated server (Ubuntu) ping is down. The support asked me to enter ILO. I have accessed the remote console and this is what i see: http://prntscr.com/81nqn2

And this is ILO event log: http://prntscr.com/81naj0

And this the network: http://prntscr.com/81nhrp

Before the server ping went down. I used to see Error establishing connection to Database.

Now even if i keep restarting I still get ping down.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Your box has not boot. It can't find it's system drive and fallbax into a minimal system (busybox). That might be a networking issue from the provider side, i.e the instance you rent cannot mount it's drive through iSCSI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback Sir. So you are suggesting that it from their end and They are supposed to fix not me ?

Comment: If you specify your provider's name and the step you used to create that box, we might be able to know whether you missed some configuration or if it's from their end.

Comment: My provider is online.net. I connected to the user panel , I clicked access ILO. The server has been running perfectly for the past months. Only today this issue occurs. This is what i see: http://prntscr.com/81omvo

Comment: and these are the buttons that I have: http://prntscr.com/81oo4v

Comment: Then I guess something went wrong with the hard drive, your box has gone done, and can't reboot (from http://prntscr.com/81nqn2). Give those information to the support.

Comment: Did you try the reboot button? Btw I'm surprised that online.net doesn't have a failover plan for it's VMs disks.

Comment: Yes, I tried the reboot button many times, but same results. I will send them now what you have suggested Sir. I really can't thank you enough, very kind of you!

Comment: I see failover in here: http://prntscr.com/81oum3

Comment: I clicked hardware watch and reported hardware issue. Will that help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server's boot disk is damaged.  Boot from a recovery environment (CD or managed), log in as root and start:

```
fsck -C -M /dev/sda1
fsck -C -M /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Short, simple, effective =)